# Get date and time on the same line

Tags: powershell, command-line

I can use `date /t` and `time /t` to get the date and time, but it doesn't display it next to each other. I wanted to make it do that and display like this:

```
Current Date & Time
-------------------

11/27/2013 10:43:05 AM
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try the following (PowerShell):

```
Get-Date -Format G

27.11.2013 17:10:23
```

The format is defined with the system's regional settings, so for me this is what I get, but if you're regional date/time format is what you want, it should show up like you want.

```
(Get-Date).ToString()
```

would probably also work.

UPDATE:

```
"Date and time is: $((Get-Date).ToString())"
```

Comment: `ToString()` is a generic function for objects, so it was logical. I just needed to see if it contained seconds. `-format` is a powershell "function" used for string manipulation(and certain objects like datetime). Format specifiers can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That works. How did you know to use -Format G or .ToString() ? And how to make it look like "Current Date: 27.11.2013 17:10:23"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Try `"" | Select-Object @{n="Current Date";e={(Get-Date).ToString()}}` and `"Current Date: $((Get-Date).ToString())"` depending on it you want an object(first) or just a string(second).

Comment: I want to output the date and time on one line with a title next to it that says: "Date and time is: ___________ "

Comment: Use the second approach in my comment and just replce the text in the beginning

Comment: `ToString()` is not necessary when converting an object to string (which is what happens if you embed it in a subexpression inside a string).

Comment: That may be, but it doesn't hurt either. I try to avoid shortcuts when I'm explaining to others. :-)

Comment: `Get-Date -Format o` has sub-second resolution (if available). Example: `2018-10-30T16:00:08.7328176+01:00`

Answer (score 31):

In PowerShell this is trivial:

```
(Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')
```

In `cmd` it's somewhat complicated:

```
rem Get the date and time in a locale-agnostic way
for /f %%x in ('wmic path win32_localtime get /format:list ^| findstr "="') do set %%x
rem Leading zeroes for everything that could be only one digit
set Month=0%Month%
set Day=0%Day%
rem Hours need special attention if one wants 12-hour time (who wants that?)
if %Hour% GEQ 12 (set AMPM=PM) else (set AMPM=AM)
set /a Hour=Hour %% 12
if %Hour%==0 (set Hour=12)
set Hour=0%Hour%
set Minute=0%Minute%
set Second=0%Second%
set Month=%Month:~-2%
set Day=%Day:~-2%
set Hour=%Hour:~-2%
set Minute=%Minute:~-2%
set Second=%Second:~-2%
rem Now you can just create your output string
echo %Month%/%Day%/%Year% %Hour%:%Minute%:%Second% %AMPM%
```

Note that lots of code is wasted on supporting that weird date and time format. And leading zeroes if necessary. Note also that this code works regardless of the user's regional and language settings. It does not depend on the user's date format, for example (which for me is ISO 8601 anyway).

Comment: Yeah that is much complicated for something so simple.

Comment: Well, as noted, this is locale-independent, so you can create any date format you like with it. That's where the complexity comes from.

Answer (score 2):

You can use as well the .NET DateTime in powershell:

```
Write-Host "Current datetime is $([System.Datetime]::Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss"))"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am no wizard with cmd.exe, but this works. There may be an easier way!

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('date /t') do (
   set d=%%a
)
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('time /t') do (
   set t=%%a
)
REM Add those puppies together
set "dt=%d% %t%"
echo %dt%
27/11/2013  16:04
```

Comment: Very much more complicated than I had imagined. Do you know how to do this in powershell?

Comment: No sorry, I lost interest in Windows with XP3 around 7 years ago! Maybe someone who knows powershell will see what I have done and be able to work out how to do that in powershell.

Comment: You could get the exact same thing in PowerShell with `"$(cmd /c date /t) $(cmd /c time /t)"` but I beg you not to.

Comment: Nice answer, Joey - and marked as such. If MS keep improving they'll soon be getting nearly as good as Unix/Linux ;-)

Comment: Well, the canonical PowerShell variant would be just `Get-Date` or `[DateTime]::Now` – and formatting into the desired format upon output. In my eyes PowerShell is far superiour to `bash` and its ilk for the sole reason that it passes objects on the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

For CMD, Why not the simple:

```
C:\temp\test>ECHO %DATE% %TIME%
Mon 06/24/2019 18:00:17.63
```

If you want to strip off the Day at the beginning, here's a condensed version of what Joey did, using substrings.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set timestamp=%dt:~0,4%/%dt:~4,2%/%dt:~6,2% %dt:~8,2%:%dt:~10,2%:%dt:~12,2%
ECHO %timestamp%

2019/06/24 17:56:43
```

2019/06/24 17:56:43

Answer (score 1):

thank you all i was looking for inline date and time column string.

#date time sample
Select-Object **@{ l='DateTime'; e={ (Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMddHHmm")} }**

here is the full script below.  for remote query

```
do {
$MHEdate = (Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMddHHmmss") # example output 20161122. 
$OutputDir = "C:\tools\pshell\LOG\"
$logoname = 'getcoonections-filter-' + $MHEdate1 + '.csv'
$OutputFile1 = Join-Path $OutputDir $logoname

Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerName {

#output to csv 
get-nettcpconnection | select local*,remote*,state,@{Name="Process";Expression={(Get-Process -Id $_.OwningProcess).ProcessName}},@{Name="ProcessID";Expression={(Get-Process -Id $_.OwningProcess).Id}}| Where-Object {($_.RemoteAddress -notcontains '0.0.0.0') -and ($_.RemoteAddress -notcontains '127.0.0.1') -and ($_.RemoteAddress -notcontains '::') -and ($_.RemoteAddress -notcontains '::1')} #|Where-Object{ $_.remoteaddress -Contains '168.135.115.248'} 

 # start-sleep -Seconds 15
 
 }| Select-Object @{ l='DateTime'; e={ (Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMddHHmm")} },PSComputerName,LocalAddress,LocalPort,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,State,Process,ProcessID | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile1 -NoTypeInformation -Append
 #Import-Csv $OutputFile1 |Out-GridView

 write-host -ForegroundColor Green $Time "query output file is ---> " $OutputFile1
 Start-Sleep 120
}until($infinity)
```